# OpenVPN Client connects to host server but internet does not work on client

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, desktop-computer, hosting

I have searched everywhere for an answer and I am still at a loss.  I have setup an OpenVPN host server on a windows PC on a personal network.  When I  initiate a connection to the server on the client it connects like normal, however the first concerning thing is the upload / download speed is in bytes and kilobytes which seems really rather slow, and when I attempt to access any website while the VPN is connected it just times out.  I have searched and I kept seeing a lot of solutions to similar problems other people were having by altering the  `push "redirect-gateway def1"` to `push "redirect-gateway def"`.  This solution hasn't seem to do anything for me.  I am really stuck and any help would be appreciated.

Server Configuration:

```
# Specify a port, a protocol and a device type
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
# Specify paths to server certificates
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\server.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh.pem"
# Specify the settings of the IP network your VPN clients will get their IP addresses from
server 10.24.1.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def"
# If you want to allow your clients to connect using the same key, enable the duplicate-cn option (not recommended)
# duplicate-cn
# TLS protection
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\ta.key" 0
cipher AES-256-GCM
# Other options
keepalive 20 60
persist-key
persist-tun
status "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\status.log"
log "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
verb 3
```

Client Configuration:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote (Host Server Public IP) 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-GCM
connect-retry-max 25
verb 3
```